# Can SVM with polynomial kernel be used for binary classification

Tags: matlab

I want to use SVM with polynomial kernel for my binary classification problem? Can SVM with polynomial kernel be used for binary classification?

Comment: Of course it can. SVM was originally formulated for the binary classification problem.

Answer (score 1):

The *Kernel Functions* are independent from multi-class classification. There purpose is to transform non-linearly seperatable data into an higher dimensional feature space. This allows the *SVM* to learn non-linear decision boundaries. So, as stated before,  the answer is yes. You can use the *RBF* for binary classification. *SVMs* are inherently binary classifiers.

It's interesting that you want to choose the *Kernel Function* before proper evaluation.
I'd recommend you to test all the functions and see which one performs best on your data.  It's hard to determine this by simply viewing the data...depending on your dimensions.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you should consider accepting it or update your question accordingly.